# gem client_side_validations and fields_for nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I am trying to use the gem on a nested form
https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations

My code is

```
 <%= form_for  Question.new, remote: true, validate: true do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_area :text, cols: 30, rows: 8 %>
   <%= fields_for UnrosteredWork.new, :validate => true do |work_fields| %>
      <%= work_fields.text_field :minutes"%>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit "Reply" %>
 <% end %>
```

The gem works fine with my **:text** field.

I am trying to get the gem to work with the **:minutes** field

Right now, no client side validation is performed.

If break this field out into a separate form

```
  <%= form_for UnrosteredWork.new, :validate => true do |work_fields| %>
   <%= work_fields.text_field :minutes%>
  <% end %>
```

Client side validation works fine on the **:minutes** field.

NOTE I was using  version 3.2 of the gem. I am running rails 3.2 app. 
I did try upgrade the gem to

```
gem 'client_side_validations', github: "bcardarella/client_side_validations", :branch => "4-0-beta"
```

However that didn't help.

Anyone had any success with nested forms before?

Comment: try using simple_form. that might help you

Comment: had a go with simple_form, didn't have much luck getting it to work with client side validation gem for nested form

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution ? i think its to do with the name of the input field - i've hit this problem just now

When rails nenders nested fields it renames them I think this is the break down as the validator cant find the input field name  ?